# Rails real-time logger on webpage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm transferring a Ruby app I once made into Rails.
Now the app does some calculations that take a while (up to infinity (in theory) if you like :p).
To show a user the status of everything, I previously used the console. Now, obviously, I want my browser to show this.

Does anyone has any pointers where to start reading/exmples/gems/ideas?
I'm pretty new to web development, but I've heard of jQuery, that could possibly do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding you have two options to do this

1 - using some kind of a server push method to be implemented. You may use following components

juggernaut (http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/ )
http://www.ape-project.org/

2 - Using PeriodicalUpdater with JQuery. This will send a request to the server in a given time interval.

You can populate db table, mem-cache or any datastore with your status and write a method to read and return value, that method can be called via Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater

I have done this, but this is killing the performance as it request the server (in mycase it was every 5 seconds)

Even though I personally haven't done, I prefer the server-push option is the methodical way to go

HTH

cheers

sameera

Comment: Thanks, it will take some time before I've implemented everything, but the juggernaut component looks exactly like what I need.
Your second option was something I had in mind first.

Comment: I got some tips from friends on how to implement the second option. I don't expect a lot of performance problems since I expect a few users at one time.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @SirLenz0rlot, Glad that it could help, If you need further hand let me know, might be able to do something. :)

Answer (score 3):

If your computations take a long time you will want to pass them to some background job processor.  There are several several gems that can help you do this.  Here are a few with tutorial how to use them with Rails.

- [Sidekiq](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq) - Railscasts
- [Delayed Job (Revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job-revised) - Railscast
- [Delayed Job](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job) - Railscast
- [Resque](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) - Railscast

Providing a web interface to display the processing status of the calculation can be done in a number of ways.  One way might be with polling.

- [Polling for Changes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/229-polling-for-changes-revised) - Railscast

Answer (score 1):

Rails [live streaming](http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/08/03/why-rails-4-live-streaming-is-a-big-deal/) currently in rails 4. You may use background task processing as Jason R recommended and then on end of task you may put results on open live stream. For example using [redis pub/sub](http://www.beilabs.com/2013/05/02/redis-pub-sub-and-rails-4-streaming) for returning async results from workers to live stream controller.

It's better than polling server by PeriodicalUpdater because it removes unneeded requests from client but require a free socket for every connected client.

Answer (score 0):

I just find super-tool :) Add this script to your project:

```
  <script src='https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vitalyp/9441352/raw/5be994fbc78bd2bcc7ad31192f095c888d02f819/myconsole.js'></script>
```

and somewhere in `document.ready` (or from browser console), envoke function:

```
pop_console();
```

It displays a window with `console.log(...)` strings.